# How to solve $5x^2<5^{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I solve the following inequality?
$$5x^2<5^{x+2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2\cdot5<5^{x+2}$$
$$x^2<5^{x+1}$$
Let $x<0$. Then $f(x)=x^2 -$ decreasing function, $g(x)=5^{x+1} -$ increasing function. $$f(x)=g(x) \Leftrightarrow x=-1$$
If $x\ge0$ then $5^{x+1}>x^2$

[image]

Answer: $x>-1$

Comment: I don't agree: the exponential curve is erroneous.

Comment: "the exponential curve is erroneous". Why?

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. I was abused by the fact that I didn't see any part of the exponential curve in the first quadrant.

Comment: @Macavity: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is: **$x<-1$.**

Here is an intuitive approach (corrected when I compared my solution with the solution of Roman83) followed by a complete proof.

**Intuitive approach, with hints for a solution :**

- First of all, work with an equivalent inequality (what can be simplified ?).
- Then draw the graphical representation of $y=x^2$ (parabola) and  $y=5 . 5^x$ (exponential). You will see that, for values of $x$ above a certain $x_0$,  the first curve is always under the second one.
- There is an evident (integer) solution.

**Rigorous proof:**

As the problem is equivalent to $x^2 5^{-x}<5$, let us give the name :

$$g(x):=x^2 5^{-x}=x^2 e^{-ax}$$ with $$a:=\ln(5)>0.$$

This rather classical kind of function has the following derivative:

$$g'(x)=x(2-x\ln(a))e^{-ax}$$

The sign of this derivative is the sign of $x(2-x\ln(a))$ which is
$>0$ iff $0<x<b$ where $b=\frac{2}{\ln(a)}$. Thus on this interval, $f$ is increasing. On the complementary set, made of 2 infinite intervals, it is decreasing. The study of limits show that the variations of $f$ can be symbolized thus:

$$f(x) : +\infty \ \searrow \ 0 \ \nearrow \ f(b) \ \searrow 0_+$$

As $f(-1)=5$, the answer $x<-1$ will result from the fact that $f(b)<5$.

Why do we have $f(b)<5$ ? This is due to the fact that, having  $b=\frac{2}{\ln(5)}\approx 1.24267$, we have the following "bracketing": $1<b<1.5$. Therefore:

$$f(b)=b^2 \times  e^{-ab}<1.5 \times e^{-ln(5)}=1.5 \times \frac{1}{5}=0.3<5.$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The inequality, for $x\ne0$, can also be written
$$
(x+2)\log5>\log 5+2\log|x|
$$
(at $x=0$ it is certainly satisfied), or else
$$
x\log 5-2\log|x|+\log 5>0
$$
So we want to find where the function $f(x)=x\log 5-2\log|x|+\log5>0$.

We have
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\log 5-\frac{2}{x}=\frac{x\log 5-2}{x}
$$
which is positive for $x<0$ or $x>2/\log5$. Thus the function is increasing in the interval $(-\infty,0)$, decreasing in $(0,2/\log5)$ and increasing in $(2/\log5,\infty)$.

The local minimum at $x=2/\log5$ is
$$
f(2/\log5)=2-2\log\frac{2}{\log5}+\log5>0
$$
implying that $f$ is positive on $(0,\infty)$.

Thus the inequality is satisfied for $x>x_0$, where $x_0$ is the only value where $f(x)=0$.

Since $f(-1)=-\log 5+0+\log5=0$, we have the answer: the inequality is satisfied for $x>-1$.

Comment: Interesting solution [+1]. May be, at the beginning, it could be said (this is important to my eyes for students' education) to explain why we have equivalence : 1) the given inequality is equivalent to $|x|^2<5^{x+1}$ and 2) this inequality is still equivalent to the inequality obtained by taking the ln of LHS and of the RHS because ln is (bijective) increasing.

Comment: @JeanMarie Your comment seems sufficient; your solution is interesting too; the important thing is *not* to consider the “more natural” function $5^{x+2}-5x^2$, which leads to more difficult computations.